# Display:Inline-Block Ignored

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is driving me insane, and I just can't figure out the cause. I have a JSP application that is connected to bootstrap. First of all, I am by no means an expert in CSS, and am green in that area. My issue is that inline-block just will not work. My bootstrap is used for the collapse plugin that allows me to use a menu button instead of the regular menu in smartphones.
When I use a desktop-size, the menu items are displayed in block format (vertical), even though I have used display: inline-block. Here's my code, and if anyone has an idea why inline-block is not working please let me know.

The html:

```
 <ul id="menu-items" class="navbar-collapse collapse menubar-items">
                <li>
                    <a class="menuItems" href="home.jsp">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="menuItems" href="business.jsp">Business</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="menuItems" href="new-form.jsp">New Order</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="menuItems" href="logout.do">Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

The css:

```
#menu-items {
    min-width: 250px;
    background: #CFC3F8;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #888888;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}

#menu-items li {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-left: solid white 2px;
    color: #332419;

    //The attempt
    display: inline-block;
}

#menu-items li a.menuItems {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu-items li a.menuItems:hover {
    color: #332419;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

//ensuring that bootstrap doesn't override it

.navbar-collapse li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.collapse li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: You're forcing the width of the "li" elements to be the 100% of its parent. Probably this is forcing the items to stack, since each one fills the entire line...